# Why is postgres database automatically deleted?

Tags: windows, postgresql, pgadmin

I am using PostgreSQL and pgAdmin tool for viewing of databases.

I found that in pgAdmin my all databases were not there (deleted) and the last automatic backup has done of 0 Kb.

Postgres was installed in C:/ drive but I couldn't find anything at system level.

Please any one can give suggestion in this?

Comment: Neither Postgres nor pgAdmin deletes anything automatically. It must be something on your computer. Maybe you caught yourself a virus or malware. And "databases" in pgAdmin are just "connection information" to an existing database server, they are not "real databases". So even if the connection information to some (possibly remote) server has been removed from pgAdmin, that doesn't mean that (remote) database (or server) has been deleted.

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name i got your point. As my postgres installed on C:/ drive and it's server machine which runs on cloud, Can it be case because of any server update which wiped out databases?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this on your local machine cmd prompt

psql -U postgres -d postgres -c "SELECT datname FROM pg_database;"